# Is there a Tabbed Connection SSH Manager for Linux?

Tags: ssh, software-recommendation, gui

I am looking for a free tabbed ssh manager to replace GnomeConnectionManager. I liked SuperPutty in Windows.

Is there any alternative? What would you recommend?

Reminna is cool but doesn't seem to support multi-server tabs on the same window.

Comment: What feature set are you looking for exactly other than just having tabs?

Comment: yes some categorized folder-like system for connections where I can categorize saved connections ... and having the option for multiple tabs ... gnome conneciton manager was actually quite nice tho only supports one level of folders  ...